# Errors in ResetPasswords.php Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I haven't modified the ResetPasswords.php in my project but dunno why visual studio code says I have 2 errors in the ResetPasswords.php file.

Gonna post the code of the ResetPasswords.php file and explain where visual studio code says there is an error and what it is.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);


    }

    /**
     * Set the user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setUserPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($response)], 200);
        }

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

The function that has errors is the resetPassword function

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
        {
            $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);
    
            $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
    
            $user->save();
    
            event(new PasswordReset($user));
    
            $this->guard()->login($user);
    
    
        }
```

Visual Studio code says about the setRememberToken() and save() methods that are undefined.

Also in this line of code  `$this->guard()->login($user);` I get this error

```
Expected type 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable'. Found 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword'.intelephense(1006)
```

It is odd for me that Visual Studio Code says there are errors in those files because I haven't touched them.

I am asking the question because I can't change Reset Passwords. I can send the link via email, open the form to input the new password and confirm it and after that log in but the password never updates, after I log out I can only enter with the old password.

Don't know if this info is relevant but this is how my users table looks like. It is a custom users table.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idPersona` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_FK` (`idPersona`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

If you need any extra info I can gladly provide it. I have no idea why I can't reset the passwords specially because I get no error in runtime and I think this errors in the ResetPasswords.php may be the cause. If the stuff in the ResetPasswords.php file is irelevant to why I can't reset the passwords even when everything else works fine then I can change the question because thats the main problem.

Comment: For more info I explain in another question how the password doesn't change when doing all the steps in the forgot password functionality in this question of StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932657/laravel-not-reseting-password-laravel-8

Comment: FYI phpstorm also say this kind of things sometimes. To me, it's just that all parts of Laravel are not typehinted and/or use magic methods that our ide don't understand.

Comment: If this code works but vscode mistakenly says there are errors in it then I suggest you tag it as a vscode question since that's where your real issue is.

Comment: The thing is that the code doesn't fully works, because the password in the end never resets @apokyfos, I placed the link to another question of mine because thats my real problem. That the password doesn't reset for me but nobody have been able to help me. If you could check the question I linked I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Laravel 8 does not have the `ResetsPasswords` facade. Always check the upgrade docs. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade